# update datagridview colums by selecting value from datagridcombox is not working properly

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I have `DataGridView` in that one combobox the combobox values are loaded from one table after selecting combobox value i want to update other columns with respective data but this is working only for one row i want update all row.. please give any suggestion for code change.

```
private void dataGridView2_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)  
{
    if (dataGridView2.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView2.Rows.Count)-1; i++)
        {

            try
            {
                if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() != "")
                {
                    ConnectionDB gridRdata = new ConnectionDB("SELECT * FROM Ready_Made_Master WHERE RM_Name='" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "';");
                                DataTable redydata = gridRdata.returntable();
                                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = redydata.Rows[i][2].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch
            {


            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the for loop,try rebinding the gridview ie

```
for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView2.Rows.Count)-1; i++)
{

}
ConnectionDB gridRdata = new ConnectionDB("SELECT * FROM Ready_Made_Master");
DataTable redydata = gridRdata.returntable();
gridRdata .Datasource=redydata ;
gridRdata .Databind();
```

Please make the necessary chnges in Select Statement.